# Alternatives to longurl API?

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, url-shortener

I am trying to expand shortened urls using javascript (a chrome extension).
 Currently I am using LongURL API and it takes too much time to respond. Are there anyother alternatives I could use? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to code this API yourself? It's incredibly simple. Just make a CURL call to the given URL and fetch the Location of the target URL from the headers.

Example:

```
curl --head http://bit.ly/1RmnUT
```

Comment: Clarification: This curl call will need to go from the server side. Your page will need to make an AJAX call to this server side code and fetch the target URL.

Comment: I agree that this would work but I'm trying to do it in the client side itself. Any ideas?

Comment: @user926321: what about using a XHR?

Comment: @check_ca i dont quite understand.. i use xhr to call the longurl api which takes a very long time..

Comment: @user926321: I meant using an XHR to get the HTTP HEAD directly from http://bit.ly/1RmnUT but I forgot that redirections (301, 302, 303, or 307) were transparent for XHR requests...